# Swift: UITableView Section Heading style

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that has several headers, but the font size is much bigger than I want:

[image]

I have seen in the system preferences that Apple use a section heading in capitals using a smaller font size, bottom aligned like this:

[image]

I know I can use viewForHeaderInSection to create my own layout, but my question is there a simple option that will invoke this standard OS style, without reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out to be easy:

[image]

You need to simply select the 'Grouped' style.

Answer (score 6):

For smaller font size and bottom aligned like system preferences that Apple use a section heading in capitals, we have to use the delegate method of UITableView.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        let sectionLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 28, width:
            tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
        sectionLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
        sectionLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        sectionLabel.text = "NETWORK SETTINGS"
        sectionLabel.sizeToFit()
        headerView.addSubview(sectionLabel)

        return headerView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
```

You can use this method to set custom font family and alignment of section title.

viewForHeaderInSection method is just use for set the default font family and alignment of section title.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: works great thank you. But what if I desire the sectionLabel to be centered horizontally? please... thank you. I tried with no luck. The frame CGRect needs changing I assume. I tried to then add: sectionLabel.textAlignment = .center  with no luck.